# ListView opens activity when Item is clicked?

Tags: android, listview, onclick, android-listview

Im trying to built this app which simple consist of a ListView and different other activities that will be called when an item from the view is clicked. However, I am unable to implement a working onclicklistener in the main activity. With the code below, I am unable to open the activity.

Heres the code:

```
public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {
    switch( position )
    {
       case 0:  Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(this, TempuraActivity.class);     
                startActivity(newActivity0);
                break;
       case 1:  Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(this, TempuraActivity.class);     
                startActivity(newActivity1);
                break;
       case 2:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(this, TempuraActivity.class);     
                startActivity(newActivity2);
                break;
       case 3:  Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(this, TempuraActivity.class);     
                startActivity(newActivity3);
                break;
       case 4:  Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(this, TempuraActivity.class);     
                startActivity(newActivity4);
                break;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :) Comment if U need to see the full code, I will update in the post. Thanks!

**Thanks for all the Replies!**
Heres the full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Vector<RowData> data;
RowData rd;

static final String[] title = new String[] {
    "Christmas Crepes", "Dorayaki", "Corned Beef", "Tempura"
    };

static final String[] release = new String[] {
"New!", "New!", "4 months ago", "New!"
};

static final String[] description = new String[] {
    "Blehh..","Pam pam pam","new era","Steve Jobs is dead"
    };

static final String[] difficulty = new String[] {
"Hard","Easy","Medium","Hard"
};

static final String[] serves = new String[] {
"4 persons","2 persons","2 cups","1 person"
};

static final String[] time = new String[] {
"40 mins","20 mins","50 mins","120 mins"
};

private Integer[] imgid = {
  R.drawable.thumbone,R.drawable.thumbtwo,R.drawable.thumbthree,
  R.drawable.thumbfour
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
data = new Vector<RowData>();
for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++){

try {
rd = new       RowData(i,title[i],release[i],description[i],difficulty[i],serves[i],time[i]);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   data.add(rd);
   }
   CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list, android.R.id.list, data);
   setListAdapter(adapter);
   getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
   }
   public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {
    switch( position )
    {
       case 0:  Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(this, TempuraActivity.class);     
                startActivity(newActivity0);
                break;
       case 1:  Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(this, TempuraActivity.class);     
                startActivity(newActivity1);
                break;
       case 2:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(this, TempuraActivity.class);     
                startActivity(newActivity2);
                break;
       case 3:  Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(this, TempuraActivity.class);     
                startActivity(newActivity3);
                break;
       case 4:  Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(this, TempuraActivity.class);     
                startActivity(newActivity4);
                break;
    }
}
   private class RowData {
   protected int mId;
   protected String mTitle;
   protected String mRelease;
   protected String mDescription;
   protected String mDifficulty;
   protected String mServes;
   protected String mTime;
   RowData(int id, String title, String release, String description, String difficulty, String serves, String time){
   mId=id;
   mTitle = title;
   mRelease = release;
   mDescription = description;
   mDifficulty = difficulty;
   mServes = serves;
   mTime = time;
   }
   @Override
   public String toString() {
           return mId+" "+mTitle+" "+mRelease+" "+mDescription+" "+mDifficulty+" "+mServes+" "+mTime;
   }
}
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {               

super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
}
  @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   

   ViewHolder holder = null;
   TextView title = null;
   TextView release = null;
   TextView description = null;
   TextView difficulty = null;
   TextView serves = null;
   TextView time = null;
   ImageView thumbnail=null;
   RowData rowData= getItem(position);
   if(null == convertView){
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
}
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         title = holder.gettitle();
         title.setText(rowData.mTitle);
         release = holder.getdescription();
         release.setText(rowData.mRelease);
         description = holder.getrelease();
         description.setText(rowData.mDescription);
         difficulty = holder.getdifficulty();
         difficulty.setText(rowData.mDifficulty);
         serves = holder.getserves();
         serves.setText(rowData.mServes);
         time = holder.gettime();
         time.setText(rowData.mTime);

         thumbnail=holder.getImage();
         thumbnail.setImageResource(imgid[rowData.mId]);
         return convertView;
}
        private class ViewHolder {
        private View mRow;
        private TextView title = null;
        private TextView release = null;
        private TextView description = null;
        private TextView difficulty = null;
        private TextView serves = null;
        private TextView time = null;
        private ImageView thumbnail=null; 

        public ViewHolder(View row) {
        mRow = row;
}
    public TextView gettitle() {
         if(null == title){
             title = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.title);
            }
        return title;
     }     

    public TextView getrelease() {
        if(null == release){
            release = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.release);
           }
       return release;
    } 

     public TextView getdescription() {
         if(null == description){
              description = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.description);
                }
       return description;
     }
     public TextView getdifficulty() {
         if(null == difficulty){
             difficulty = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.difficulty);
            }
        return difficulty;
     }  
     public TextView getserves() {
         if(null == serves){
             serves = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.serves);
            }
        return serves;
     }  
     public TextView gettime() {
         if(null == time){
             time = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.title);
            }
        return time;
     }  

    public ImageView getImage() {
         if(null == thumbnail){
              thumbnail = (ImageView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                                  }
            return thumbnail;
        }
     }            
   }
}
```

If there are any better method to achieve what my app should, please post! Im in desperate need to finish this for once!

Comment: What happens when you click? Does it enter the switch? Does it crash?

Comment: Post the whole code, there seems to be some problem with implementation, For eg: the code should in onItemClick rather than setOnItemClickListener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Change

```
public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
  int position, long id) {
```

To

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
```

And it should work.

**ORIGINAL**

Your code is a little confusing, a [`setOnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) exists but you need to actually pass the method a [`onItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) object (or anonymous class).

Perhaps you are looking for something like this in your ListActivity.

```
final ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View paramView, int paramInt,
            long paramLong) {
        switch( position )
{
   case 0:  Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, TempuraActivity.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity0);
            break;
   case 1:  Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, TempuraActivity.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity1);
            break;
   case 2:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, TempuraActivity.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity2);
            break;
   case 3:  Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, TempuraActivity.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity3);
            break;
   case 4:  Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, TempuraActivity.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity4);
            break;
}              
    }
});
```

Here you can implement your switch statement inside the [`onItemClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) method of the [`onItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) and it should work.

Note: You will have to change `this` to YourActivity.this as you will be inside an inner class and will need to reference the outer activity class.

Alternatively you could override [onListItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29):

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // ... put switch statement here
}
```

In your list activity to eliminate the additional call to `getListView()`

If this doesn't answer your question please full code

Comment: I changed what u told me in ur update, but when I click, it force closes. But seems like ur method has helped a bit. Before nothing happened when  click, and now it force closes. So theres basically a catch within that line. :(

Comment: I suspect I have answered you initial question then (although I maybe wrong). If you think the new problem is linked to the original problem of the listener then post the error logs. If not then create a new question as it might be that your new activities are crashing the app.

Comment: OH MY GOD! My bad! I havent declared the activity in the Manifest! And yes, your answer was HELPING! THANKS A LOT! A LOT!