# Open listview on clicking list items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, nested-lists

I would like to open a **listview** by clicking on list items, which means when I need to show some categories in a list view and if I want that when I click on any of those categories then another **listview** should open with subcategories. And the same with working with subcategories, that when I click on subcategories then another **listview** should open with related sub-subcategories and viceversa.

**Please tell me how can i do the above if i want same listview for all operations?**

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more context for your question. Show some code.

Comment: I have not started code yet, don't know what to use either listview or anything else for this...

Comment: Start here http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/

Comment: Thanks @ramaral and Marco Biscaro for suggestions, I am looking in your suggestions,I will let you know.

Comment: I think you look for something like ExpandableListView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: Thanks @coelho but i am not looking for ExpandableListView.....when you go my question where i want create listview that popup when we click on subcategories and when i click on that subcategories another list should popup with sub-subcategories.... and when press back button it go back to previous categories...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you are trying achieve is a listview with a onItemClick, this question has been asked numerous times. Below are solutions to your question..

[custom Listview Start new activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959576/custom-listview-start-new-activity)

[How I can start a Activity if I click in A Item in a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836937/how-i-can-start-a-activity-if-i-click-in-a-item-in-a-listview)

[How to go to a particular activity on list item click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289227/how-to-go-to-a-particular-activity-on-list-item-click)

[ListView opens activity when Item is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745196/listview-opens-activity-when-item-is-clicked)

Hope this help, since no one was able to answer your question.